PostgreSQL: How is the uuid datatype sorted?
I have a system which uses the proposed UUID7 format for its uuid values.
UUID7 has timestamp encoded into into its value.
Does PostgreSQL document how ORDER BY clauses work with the UUID data type?
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html
There are no notes on sorting here.
lab7=# SELECT resource_id, uuid, created_timestamp from resource where "name" in ('ABC000004',
 'ABC000003') order by uuid, "name" desc;
 resource_id |                 uuid                 |     created_timestamp
      
-------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------
------
    17704701 | 018ec350-6976-79d5-b0f5-41af99b98fa4 | 2024-04-09 14:43:30.6
09909
    17704718 | 018ec353-ee50-7765-9e8b-3ebf22654662 | 2024-04-09 14:47:21.3
78086

Comparing the leftmost characters (assuming this was a string), I would expect
018ec353 to be in the result set before 018ec350.  As this is not stored as a string, that assumption may be naive.
Performance wise, sorting by resource_id here or create_timestamp is more performant, but I would have expected the sorting on the uniquely incrementing resource_id, the globally unique uuid, and the created_timestamp to all be alignment. (Newest created entry sorts first when order by desc)
Are there any details on how this sorting is performed and why my assumptions are wrong?

Why do you expect 018ec353 to be sorted before 018ec350? Perhaps you're thinking that desc in the order by clause applies to both columns?

Thanks @mustaccio - that's exactly right!  I had wrongly assumed DESC was applying to both sort conditions.  Had I used a larger result set I may have noticed that the UUID was ascending instead of descending. Looks like UUID7s are sortable w.r.t time! If you make this an Answer I can mark it as correct?

This is an X-Y Problem™ - you seem to assume that the desc modifier applies to all columns in the order by clause, while it applies only to "name", and uuid is sorted in the ascending order by default.
To answer the actual question, the proposed changes to RFC 4122 include this statement:

UUIDv6 and UUIDv7 are designed so that implementations that require sorting (e.g. database indexes) SHOULD sort as opaque raw bytes, without need for parsing or introspection.

Postgres compares UUIDs as such, using memcmp().

Agreed that after applying DESC directly to the uuid column ORDER BY, uuids and their separate timestamp column are aligned in the expected order.  Thanks again for the detailed answer.
